# Regular Expression to extract from field

Tags: regex

I have a string that contains the following;

```
Penicillin S =2 Vancomycin S =1;
```

And I am looking for a Regular expression, that would extract to;

```
- "Penicillin S =2" ;
- "Vancomycin S =1";
```

Comment: Where are the `-` characters coming from in the result, since they're not in the original string?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you want to catch the numbers then here it is:
(Penicillin S =(\d+)) (Vancomycin S =(\d+))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`(.*?=\d+)`

It will match and capture the part before the `=` and the numbers after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the words, a space, a letter, a space, and the equals sign followed by a number like this:

```
\b(\w+ \w =\d+\b)[; ]*
```

Replace the captured values with:

```
- "$1";\n
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW2nP4/1) should work in both Javascript and PHP. Some languages require `\1` instead of `$1`.